# How to verify who a service belongs to?

Tags: windows, service, windows-service

I am looking into the services installed in different versions of windows. Mainly Windows 7 and 10.

Is there a way to find out if the service installed belongs to Windows or another program? And if that is the case what would be a proper way to automate the search?

Comment: With powershell `gwmi win32_service | select DisplayName, pathname` then start reading

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is essentially the same as  `Get-WmiObject win32_service | select DisplayName, pathname`. That displays all the services. However, let's say I am looking specifically for windows services to start, and I would like to know if the services all are indeed a windows service, is there some kind of signature or something I can look at.

Comment: Actually they are exactly the same except that I used one more alias than you. :) There isn't any way that I am aware of and you wouldn't want to start every service that came from Microsoft anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Autoruns and Autorunsc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) are probably the easiest one-off way of doing this. The GUI version has `Services` tab and you can enable filtering on both "Windows" and more generically "Microsoft" entries.

> This utility, which has the most comprehensive knowledge of auto-starting locations of any startup monitor, shows you what programs are configured to run during system bootup or login, and when you start various built-in Windows applications like Internet Explorer, Explorer and media players. These programs and drivers include ones in your startup folder, Run, RunOnce, and other Registry keys. Autoruns reports Explorer shell extensions, toolbars, browser helper objects, Winlogon notifications, auto-start services, and much more. Autoruns goes way beyond other autostart utilities.

The command line version can display output as CSV for automated processing.

Comment: Nice! Got to love Sysinternals. If I am understanding Autoruns function correctly, it will give me the information of all the services that are setup to Autorun (as the name states) but not any that are not set in some way to start automatically. That at the very least points me in the right direction since that eliminates quite a few services. The "Verify Code Signatures" is extremely useful, especially if you are trying to find a service that might not be legitimate.

Comment: For services in particular, I think you get all registered services rather than just the ones configured to autostart.